# need to use a 'for loop' for this one. The user has to enter a sentence and any spaces must be replaced with "%"

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, input, pycharm

1. the input

   sentence = input("Please enter a sentence:")
2. the for loop (incorrect here)

   ```
   for i in sentence:
       print(sentence)
   space_loc = sentence.index(" ")
   for c in sentence:
       print(space_loc)
   for b in range(space_loc):
       print("%")
   ```
3. confused about how to get the answer out.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using **concatenation of strings** and **slicing** in this one.

```
sentence = input()
```

After taking the input simply store the length of your string

```
length = len(sentence)
```

Then iterate through every characters in the string and when you find a " ", break the string into two halves using **slicing** such that each half has one side of the string from " ". And then, join it by a "%" :-

```
for i in range(length):
    if sentence[i]==" ":
        sentence = sentence[:i] + "%" + sentence[i+1:]
```

Here, `sentence[:i]` is the part of string before the space and `sentence[i+1:]` is the part of string after the space.

Comment: Your method is more efficient! This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way of solving your query:

**Code**

```py
sentence = input("Please enter a sentence:")

ls=sentence.split()               #Creating a list of words present in sentence
new_sentence='%'.join(ls)         #Joining the list with '%'

print(new_sentence)
```

**Output**

```py
Please enter a sentence:Hello there coders!
Hello%there%coders!
```

**EDIT**

I do not understand how exactly you want to use the `for` loop here. If you just want to include a `for` loop (no restrictions), then you can do this:

**Code**

```py
ls=[]
a=0
sentence = input("Please enter a sentence:")
for i in range(0,len(sentence)):      # This loop will find the words in the sentence and store them in a list. Words are determined by checking the white space. Each space is replaced with '%'
    if sentence[i]==' ':
        ls.append(sentence[a:i])
        a=i
        ls.append('%')
ls.append(sentence[a:])              # This is to save the last word
ls1=[]
for i in ls:                         # Removing any white space inside the list
    j=i.replace(' ','')
    ls1.append(j)

print(''.join(ls1))                  # Displaying final output
```

Again, your question is very open ended and this is just one way of using `for` loop to get the desired result!

Comment: OP specifically requests a `for` loop. (Sounds like some sort of programming puzzle/test.)